# Javascript event makes infinit loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I am attaching two events to 'document' - one for some checkboxes an one button. I thought that using the jquery .on() in combination with the relevant selectors would be sufficient.
[This fiddle][1] show the example code that 'freeze' as you select the button. The checkboxed are working OK. Can anyone explain why this is happening and how this should be done?

Html:

```
<div id="main">main..
    <p>
        <input type="checkbox" class="ui-checkbox" id="checkbox0" name="inkluderfil" value="filnavn">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="inkluderfil" value="filnavn">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" name="inkluderfil" value="filnavn">
        <br>
        <br>
    </p>
</div>
<div id="buttdiv">
    <input type="submit" name="mybutt" value="A submit button">
</div>
<div id='result'></div>


$('document').ready(function () {
$(document).on("change", 'input[name="inkluderfil"]', function (event)           {
    $('#result').html('Checkbox is changed')
});

$(document).on("click", 'input[name="mybutt"]', function (event) {
    $('#result').html('mybutt is clicked')
    for (var i = 0; 3; i++) {
        console.log('objAttach2XML:' + i)
    };
});

$('#result').html('ready')
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
for (var i = 0; 3; i++) {
```

to

```
for (var i = 0; i<3; i++) {
```